# How can I fix color from an unevenly spread flash gel in Photoshop (or Lightroom)?

Tags: flash, post-processing, lighting, studio-lighting

[image]

so this is the image and as you can see, the yellow gel did not spread to the bottom left part of it. is there a way to artificially spread that (I can only do basic controls in lightroom and PS)

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Let's focus on the post processing in this one. Ask how to use Rogue flash gels on speedlites in a separate question.

Comment: Hello Null. My suggestion is that many times "post processing" is used as a crutch and not a conscience choice. As a 20 year working pro, I have seen the lack of understanding of the principles of light. If the photographer doesn't understand light and how it works and  thus how to control it will not be able to understand how to use it post processing either. Thanks for your thoughts. Scott

Answer (score 1):

Well. First of all. In my opinion it looks fine as it is. Probably more interesting than an uniform background, because as the yellow tint is iluminating her arm and the chest, it gives more separation.

But lets get into business.

I am also answering the aditional question you originally asked. Just be sure to stick evenly the gel in front of your flash. Use small pices of sticky tape.

> I can only do basic controls in lightroom and PS

Well it is time you move further and make not so basic retouching.

- First of all mask the afected zone to protect the girl from harm. Do not mask only the gray part. Spread to some of the yellow zone.

[image]

Make it as a new layer and lock the transparency. Pick a color sample from the yellow part.

[image]

Use a wide soft brush, like 500px and paint using Color as the blending mode.

[image]

You of course expand your selection to the upper zone, but I wanted to leave that natural shadowy look.

[image]

This is not the most advanced method, but a basic one so you start to explore editing using layers on Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Do some basic selection of the area. I just used a rectangular marquee. Then I prefer Lab so tweaked the b channel. If you're staying in RGB it'll be mostly the blue channel that needs adjusting:

Then use the Layer > Layer Style > Blending Options and at the bottom the Blend-If area to refine the adjustment.

There was a little bit I wasn't happy with so I did another similar curve. Inverted the mask to all black. Then painted the mask in over a few trouble areas.

Whole thing shouldn't take more than two minutes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try sampling the yellow from the top left and paint it over the grey area with Color blending mode.